# Pulseaudio no sound from speakers

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, alsa

Well, I know there are similar questions out there but none of their answers have actually solved my problem. I am running a Debian 10 (`uname -a: Linux msi-debian 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2 (2019-08-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

The thing is I haven't been able to make speakers play a sound, even though microphone and headphones work.

On the other hand, while speakers are silent they are detected by the system. This is the info about my computer:

```
$ inxi -Fx

System:    Host: msi-debian Kernel: 4.19.0-6-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.30.2 
           Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GL63 8SE v: REV:1.0 serial: <root required> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16P7 v: REV:1.0 serial: <root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: E16P7IMS.105 
           date: 11/26/2018 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 34.1 Wh condition: 49.6/53.4 Wh (93%) model: MSI BIF0_9 status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-8750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 9216 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 52992 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 801 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 
           9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia v: 418.74 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: modesetting,nouveau,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~120Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 18.3.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.19.0-6-amd64 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 6000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: 48:a4:72:bd:e7:b4 
           Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: alx v: kernel port: 3000 
           bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: 00:d8:61:05:39:c3 
           IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: 02:42:fc:9c:14:12 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.14 TiB used: 6.68 GiB (0.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Kingston model: RBUSNS8154P3256GJ size: 238.47 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM049-2GH172 size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 91.17 GiB used: 5.95 GiB (6.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
           ID-2: /home size: 137.24 GiB used: 749.6 MiB (0.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 15.82 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 297 Uptime: 1h 58m Memory: 15.51 GiB used: 3.01 GiB (19.4%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 8.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.3 inxi: 3.0.32
```

The info in pulseaudio is:

```
$ pacmd list-cards
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xa5080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "10f9"
        device.product.name = "TU106 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "TU106 High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Inactiu (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xa5410000 irq 154"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a348"
        device.product.name = "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Audio intern"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Estèreo analògic Input (priority 65, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Estèreo analògic Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Estèreo digital (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Estèreo digital (IEC958) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 5565, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51: Envolvent digital 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Envolvent digital 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 365, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 5965, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 865, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 865, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Estèreo analògic Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        off: Inactiu (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#35: Audio intern Estèreo analògic
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor/#43: Monitor of Audio intern Estèreo analògic
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#44: Audio intern Estèreo analògic
    ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

I have tried every possible profile combination through `pacmd set-profile-card` and I have no idea what to do. Moreover, through `alsamixer` I have checked that no speakers have been muted (or I thing none of them are muted):

[image: alsamixer output]

**Update:**

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY FLAT_VOLUME DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Estèreo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 2000,00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC1220 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC1220 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xa5410000 irq 154"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a348"
        device.product.name = "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Estèreo analògic"
        device.description = "Audio intern Estèreo analògic"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC1220"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec1220,14621275,00100101 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

**Update 2: Output of `alsamixer -c 0`**

[image: alsamixer -c 0]

Comment: Try running `alsamixer -c 0`: you should see "Chip: Realtek ALC1220" on the second line in the top left corner, and a lot more things to adjust.

Comment: @telcoM I've just checked it, and none of the volumes are muted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it might be the same bug that is known in Ubuntu also:

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1812693
```

This wiki has a suggestion for a workaround:

```
https://blog.kafaiworks.com/posts/arch-linux-audio-setup-on-msi-gp63/
```

The workaround is to edit the `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf` file like this:

```
[Element Headphone]
switch = off
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right

[Element Speaker]
required-any = any
switch = mute
volume = off
```

and then to restart pulseaudio (in Debian 10 it's implemented as a `systemd` per-user service):

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

If I understand the workaround correctly, it looks like the volume/mute controls for the front speakers and headphones may be somehow miswired/cross-connected.

The `hdajackretask` tool in package `alsa-tools-gui` might be helpful too: if you can find working override settings for your laptop model, you should probably [contact the Linux audio driver developers](https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Bug_Tracking) to report your findings, so the override can be made to apply automatically to that particular system model.

[MSI GL73 apparently uses the same ALC1220 sound codec and also needed the same fix in sound routing as Clevo P950.](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=284775&action=diff) As a wild guess, you might try adding a file named `/etc/modprobe.d/sound-fixup.conf` with the following content:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=clevo-p950
```

Then run `update-initramfs -u` as root to make sure the change will be effective in early boot also, then reboot and see if it results in an improvement. If MSI has wired your model the same as the GL73, this might fix it. If not, delete the `/etc/modprobe.d/sound-fixup.conf` file and run `update-initramfs -u` again to fully get rid of the option.

Comment: This bug is also found on Fedora 32 and is fixed by the steps listed here. I suspect that all MSI Laptops are affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a default sink

```
pacmd list-sinks
# use output from list-sinks:
pactl set-default-sink  alsa_output.pci-0000_02_02.0.analog-stereo
# also
pactl set-sink-volume 0 100%
pactl set-sink-mute 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's no use

Comment: Why aren't all sinks default?

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me,

So you fix the sound:

1. Open a Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T).
2. Write 'sudo su' to login as root.
3. Install via apt 'alsa-tools-gui'.
4. Logout via exit.
5. Write 'hdajackretask' and press enter.
6. Click on 'Intel Haswell HDMI' and select 'Realtek ALC3661'.
7. A lot of new entrys are visible. Select 'Show unconnected pins'.
8. Click on 'Overwrite' on Pin ID '0x1a'.
9. Click on the Context Menu and select 'Line out (Center/LFE)'.
10. Click on 'Apply now' and enter your user password.
11. Click on 'Install boot overwrite' to save the settings permanently.
12. Click on your Volume Icon on the top (Ubuntu) and remove the marker 'mute'.
13. Reboot and your sound work perfect.

Comment: This was covered in [telcoM’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539643/80216).

Answer (score -2):

Try installing pavucontrol, a pulseaudio gui.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that long ago